# Resque Scheduler running jobs but web client "Schedule" tab is empty

Tags: resque, resque-scheduler

I have resque-scheduler set up and running a job every minute. The job runs correctly, though when I visit the `Schedule` table of the resque web client the table is empty.

I would expect my job to show up on the `Schedule` tab like resque-schedule docs seems to indicate (screenshot from the docs):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out via this issue on Github -https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler/issues/541

Specifically, I needed to moved my `Resque.schedule` assignment out of the `resque:setup` rake task, and into `config/initializers/resque.rb`. See the screenshot below from the issue discussion

[image]